# How to have same user login with Two Factor for application A and without Two Factor for application B?

Tags: fusionauth

The "Two Factor" requirement is configured per user. If we have multiple applications, how do we achieve that

- for application A (e.g. a webapp) 2FA is required
- but for application B (e.g. a native app), for the same user, 2FA is not required (never, not even for the first time it is used)?

I'm aware of the `trustComputer` attribute but I don't think it helps for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Factor is at the User level in FusionAuth. This is by design since if the user has selected to protect their account, then they should be forced to provide their additional factor regardless of the Application they are logging into.

There isn't currently a way to change this behavior and we would need to understand the use case in detail as well as any security issues with allowing specific Applications to bypass two-factor authentication.

You can open a feature request on the FusionAuth GitHub issue tracker here: https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues if you want. Please provide as much detail about the use case and why some Applications allow two-factor while others don't. This will help the FusionAuth team assess the implications of adding this feature.